# How to get all content of table in sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a table named-`"dbo.COM_ConnectionLogRfmDevices"` in sql server 2008.

The table contains 7 columns named as follows:-

```
CL_ID,CL_UnitNumber,CL_RemoteIP,CL_RemotePort,CL_RecDateTime,CL_GPRS,CL_COM.
```

`CL_UnitNumber` contains unitnumber as follows:-

```
352964054838728
352964054868972
352964054839296
352964054868881
```

I want to store the content of only column-2 i.e `CL_UnitNumber value in string[] array`.

Connection string:-

```
string _ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.60;" +
             "Initial Catalog=OLTP_MTEL_DEVICES; User ID=sa; Password=pass,123;";
```

Comment: [Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically size an array I would use a List instead...

```
List<string> unitNumbers = new List<string>();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CL_UnitNumber FROM COM_ConnectionLogRfmDevices", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            unitNumbers.Add(reader.GetInt32(0)); // Or maybe reader.GetString(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this post out. Drop Entity Framework into your app and you can connect to you database and extract out your data in minutes. Very painless.

[Entity Framework - Get Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned SQL, I guess you are wanting to handle this using raw SQL commands.
Something like below should get you started.

```
string[] allRecords = null;
string sql = @"SELECT CL_UnitNumber
           FROM some table";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
            list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        allRecords = list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = new List<string>();
    var connectionString= "YOUR CONNECTION";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CL_UnitNumber FROM COM_ConnectionLogRfmDevices", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
                arr.Add(reader["CL_UnitNumber"] != DBNull.Value
                                            ? reader["CL_UnitNumber"].ToString()
                                            : "");
           }
        }

    }
    return arr.ToArray();
```